# DLLImport of the origin function in the DLL

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to call a function in `kernel32.dll` (it doesn't matter which function).  It works very good.

Now I have the following problem:

Another program injects code that hooks a function in kernel32.dll and changes its return value.  How can I call the origin function instead?

Before I could just open *My* program first then it worked fine. But in Windows 10, it calls the injected function.

I hope that I could explained it clearly.

Here is an example:

I use the function `ReadProcessMemory()`, which works very good. There is a programm which changes this function. If this program is started, I receive only 0xFF from `ReadProcessMemory()`.

In Windows 7 for example, I just have to start my program before another program changes the function.

But in Windows 10, it doesn't work anymore. I just receive 0xFF when that another program is started.

So I Import the function:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, UIntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

My function to read:

```
public static bool ReadMemory(Int64 Address, ref byte[] buffer)
{
    return ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, (UIntPtr)Address, buffer, (UIntPtr)buffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: No, that's not at all clear

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question...  you need to give me A LOT more detail.  What program is is injecting a function, what is the return value, what has it changed into?  How are you calling the function from kernel32.dll?  How about some example of the code you're using?

Comment: It's still not very clear. How can some other program modify how `ReadProcessMemory` behaves in your program? Is there some hacky injection going on? How do we know that you aren't just calling `ReadProcessMemory` incorrectly and have misdiagnosed your problem. Unless you are prepared to provide concrete details, nobody can help you. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only `kernel32.dll` is being changed you could call `ntdll.dll!NtReadVirtualMemory` (`ReadProcessMemory` itself calls this function).

If `ntdll.dll` is also seems to be changed by 3rd party process you could copy `ntdll.dll` to another temporary file (`ntdll_copy.dll`), and use it:

```
[DllImport("ntdll_copy.dll", EntryPoint = "NtReadVirtualMemory")]
private static extern bool NtReadVirtualMemory(IntPtr hProcess, UIntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Exists there a documentation? Because I called it like ReadProcessMemory but I recieve only 0Xff. But I am sure that I am doing something wrong. I will Show my Code in the answer

Comment: My Code:
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", EntryPoint = "NtReadVirtualMemory")]
private static extern bool NtReadVirtualMemory(IntPtr hProcess, UIntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    
public static bool ReadMemory(Int64 Address, ref byte[] buffer, int size)
        {
            return NtReadVirtualMemory(ProcessHandle, (UIntPtr)Address, buffer, (UIntPtr)size, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

Comment: public uint ReadUInt(long Address)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            if (ReadMemory(Address, ref buffer, 4))
                return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
            return uint.MaxValue;
        }

Comment: Class_HP_NT PTest = new Class_HP_NT();
PTest.SetProcessIDHandle("Processname");
uint mAddress = 0x52D4F560
uint mValue = PTest.ReadUInt(mAddress);
MessageBox.Show(mValue.ToString("X"));

Comment: ok now it works.
When I copy this dll, then I reiceve the message that the modul is not found. When I copy it in a temporary file it says: "Load it in a wrong Format"